# Securing API endpoint without using authorization

Tags: asp.net

Would love to get your input about this issue I'm having: My goal is to create an endpoint in my ASP.NET MVC application that I'll approach in order to send error messages in case my web app crashes during the initialization scripts. The problem is that at that point the authentication process hasn't begun so I have no token to attach to my request. How can I make sure no process outside my domain can access this endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: On your server side of your mvc you can define cors by origins. This is should not be your only solution for your security implementation.

Comment: Hi, the problem with CORS is that it's not strong enough. Anyone can fake origin in using postman. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can't spoof origin, browsers are in control of that. With postman I'm not sure. You will have to implement additional security checks with CORS.